# Convet coordinates to a different coordinate system?

Tags: lua, 2d, coordinates, converters

Hey guys im making a GUI and the image on my GUI uses the coordinate system of computers which looks like [image: this]

and my trying to convert the coordinates to a normal coordinate system like [image: this]

going crazy cant figure this out. Im using LUA right now. But when I click on the image I get the coordinates of the first coordinate system but then need to convert to the second coordinate system so it can be used in game.

what my gui looks like

[image]

So example when I select my Gui I get x=492 and y=247 which should be 0,0 for my in game coordinates. I just need a way to convert them over. One pixel is 500 meters in game so 0,1 would be 500 meters in game.

Comment: Show code, GUI screenshots - anything more concrete to help.

Comment: Updated the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that your world map doesn't extend any further past the view port, then the below should work.

```
function convertToWorldPoint(x,y)
  x = ( (x-horizontalOffset) - (worldWidth/2) ) * scale
  y = ( (y-verticalOffset) - (worldHeight/2) ) * scale
  return x,y
end
```

Where horizontal and vertical offset are the distances between the view port from the left and top of the screen and world width and height are the sizes of your world. So an example with your world might be:

```
function convertToWorldPoint(x,y)
  x = ( (x+8) - (1000/2) ) * 500
  y = ( (y+3) - (500/2) ) * 500
  return x,y
end
print(convertToWorldPoint(492,247)) -- Returns 0,0
```

Of course you might need to alter the function based on whether you can zoom in on your world or if you can pan around in your world, but since you haven't given us any of these details to work with, I'll presume that this is all you need.

Comment: I’m will be adding a zoom functionality soon just have not. Another thing to note is that I scanned the terrain for every 500 meters in game so when I move one pixel over or 0,1 that will be 500 meters so do you know how I would be able to add that to the function?

Comment: Sure, just multiply x and y by whatever the scale of your map is (in this case, 500). I will edit my answer to reflect the change.

Comment: I have two quick questions. 1.So how would I get the horizontal and vertical offset 2. The hight and width of the game world is that the hight and width of the world in game or my GUI world? Thanks for you time really appreciate it.

Comment: The offset is however much space there is between the view port (your map on the window) and the left and top sides of the screen. For instance, if you were drawing your map at the position 10,30 on your window, then 10,30 would be your x and y offset respectively. The height and width would be the height and width of your view port on the window. Again, this solution only works if your map is going to remain static and you aren't going to zoom in or pan around, in which case you'll have to account for some more offsets and scales in the function. @AHamburgler

Comment: So I would need to come up with a solution because my maps bigger then the window so it has vertical and horizontal scroll ability so you can see other area of the map (aka pan around).

Comment: For panning you should be able to just add another offset. `x = ( (x-horizontalOffset + xPanOffset) - (worldWidth/2) ) * scale`

Comment: Sorry to bother you again. So if I start my map at 0,0 that would be the offset then (so the first point I plot on my map is 0,0 then 0,1 then 0,1 ect)? Also would the panoffset be a static number as in it will not change or does it change depending on where you pan? Aging really appreciate you time!!

Comment: If you're drawing your map at 0,0 then yes your offset would be 0,0. PanOffset would be increased or decreased as you panned across the map. Please let me know if you need any more help, thank you for marking my answer as correct :)

Comment: I seem to be having an issue with the coordinates changing at the start of the gui. If I click at the top left sometimes I can get point 0,0 then other times ill get point 30,79 or something else. Another issue is when I get my X or Y axis to be correct (as in the coordinates match to the in game ones) then when I go to change the numbers for the next axis it throws off the first one. But I think this is due to the coordinates changing. I posted my whole GUI code up top.

Comment: I don't see the link to your code, I do think that whatever issue you're running into is probably in there. Comment with a pastebin link amd I'll take a look

Comment: If you need me to upload more I can zip the file and put it here.

Comment: I'll take a look once I get a chance